# Java String return method does not return

Tags: java, string, file, return

I have a method to return a string of the folder path.  CSVFile method calls another method ConfigFilePath to extract the value from a config file and return it back to be used for another condition.

```
public CSVFile(ManagedElement_T[] meInfo) {
    String path = null;
    ConfigFilePath(path);
    system.out.print("CSV "+path);
}

public String ConfigFilePath(String path) {
    final String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    final String filename = "config.properties";
    final File configFile = new File(directory+"/"+filename);

    final Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(configFile);
        prop.load(input);
        path = prop.getProperty("diretory_csv");
        System.out.println("PATH " + path);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
             // Close the file
    }

    File checkPath = new File(path.toString());
    System.out.println("CHECK " + checkPath);
    if (checkPath.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists ...");
    } else {
           //mkdir if it does not exist
    }


    return path;
}
```

Problem is, it doesn't return any var path? just says null when I print it but inside the ConfigFilePath method it seems its getting the right values based from the prints in eclipse.

```
System.out.println("PATH " + path); = C:/opt/CORBA/input
System.out.println("CHECK " + checkPath); = C:\opt\CORBA\input
System.out.print("CSV "+path); = null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is actually `pass by value` not `pass by reference`.

so when you initialized it here:

```
path = prop.getProperty("diretory_csv");
```

path wont actually `reference` that value but get destroyed when `out of scope`.

**solution**:

Get the returned value of the `ConfigFilePath` method

```
path = ConfigFilePath(path);
```

Answer (score 6):

The method `ConfigFilePath` is **returning** a value. You have to assign that returned value to the variable `path`:

```
path = ConfigFilePath(path);
```

**Note:** Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use `mixedCase` for methods/variables and use `CamelCase` for classes/interfaces

Answer (score 0):

ConfigFilePath is returning a value. You should get the result from it and put it in the path:

```
public CSVFile(ManagedElement_T[] meInfo) {
    String path = ConfigFilePath(path);
    system.out.print("CSV "+path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that java is passing method-parameters **by value**, not **by reference**. It can be confusing, since when using object types the passed value is actually an object-reference.

Let's have a look at some lines of your code:

```
public String ConfigFilePath(String path)
```

Here your method gets passed a reference to some `String` and keeps it in a local variable called `path`.

```
path = prop.getProperty("diretory_csv");
```

Now you're changing the local variable `path` to point to a new `String`-object.

```
return path;
```

This is passing out the reference as a return-value. `ConfigFilePath`'s local `path`-variable goes out of scope.

```
ConfigFilePath(path);
```

As the other answers said: in this line you're calling the method passing a reference to a `String` that is referenced by `CSVFile`'s local `path`-variable. But since passing is by value this `path`-variable will not be changed by the method-call. Your result is passed via the `return`-value - and you are ignoring that instead of assigning it to your `path`-variable.

So to sum it up:

- `ConfigFilePath()` doesn't need a parameter since it's not using the value that is passed in
- You have to assign the returned value to some variable in your calling method for it to be of any use.